# BibTeX rendering error with URL

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, urls, rendering

I put the following reference in my `.bib` file:

```
@ONLINE{MyID,
    title = {My title},
    howpublished = {\url{URL}}
}
```

However, since the used URL contains underscores, the URL is visualized as a mathematical formula (where the letters that are adjacent to underscores are visualized as subscripts). Moreover, it continues after the page margin, while it would be better to have it on the next line.

What is the best way of rendering an URL, avoiding these problems?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should try to use the `url` package.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on our [our starter page](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) to familiarize yourself further with our format.